# Put summary statistic back in main data frame

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyr

Say there is the following minimal data:

```
id    choice    relevant
1     0         0
1     0         1
1     1         1
2     1         0
2     0         1
2     0         1
```

I would like to calculate the percentage of time each value of `id` has the `choice` value 1, but only when `relevant` has the value of 1 ... and add that as a column to my original data frame. Specifically, I want:

```
id    choice    relevant   pct1
1     0         0          50
1     0         1          50
1     1         1          50
2     1         0          0
2     0         1          0
2     0         1          0
```

*Updated to get subsetting. The original approaches (without having to deal with  subsetting) were great, and I encourage people to keep the original answers as a more general case. However, I tried to extend the original solution from @DavideBottoli to the following:

```
#let df stand in for the data frame above
x = df %>% group_by(id, relevant) %>% 
    mutate(pct1 = 100*sum(relevant==1 & choice==1)/n())
```

and got this:

```
id    choice    relevant    pct1
1     0         0          0
1     0         1          50
1     1         1          50
2     1         0          0
2     0         1          0
2     0         1          0
```

**Further update: the problem is more general than the case where `choice` is an integer ... a good answer should assume that `choice` is a categorical variable, and so `mean()` is meaningless to call

***Post-further update: As of this writing, only one solution attempted to address the subset question, and for unknown reasons, it produced a vector of different length from the data being used for the actual problem. I ended up just coding a quick for-loop in python to just write the values into the spreadsheet.

Comment: You can still use `mean`, just do `mean(choice == 1)`

Comment: @Renu I hadn't thought to use booleans as numeric values here, that's a good reminder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
library(dplyr)
df <- tibble(id = c(1,1,2,2), 
                 choice = c(0,1,0,0))

output <- df %>% 
  group_by(id) %>%
  mutate(pct1 = 100 * sum(choice == 1)/n())
```

Sorry for the delay but if you want to update the first formula you can just use the following:

```
library(dplyr)
df <- tibble(id = c(1,1,1,2,2,2), 
             choice = c(0,0,1,1,0,0),
             relevant = c(0,1,1,0,1,1))

output <- df %>% 
  group_by(id) %>%
  mutate(pct1 = 100 * sum(choice == 1 & relevant == 1)/sum(relevant == 1 ))
```

Answer (score 3):

`data.table` solution

```
library(data.table)

dt <- data.table(id = c(1,1,1,1,2,2),
                 choice = c(0,1,1,1,0,0))

dt[,pct1:=100*mean(choice),by=id]
```

Answer (score 2):

Thats a good task for `ave`

```
dt <- data.frame(id = c(1,1,2,2),
             choice = c(0,1,0,0))

within(dt, pct <- ave(choice, id, FUN = mean))

#   id choice pct1
# 1  1      0  0.5
# 2  1      1  0.5
# 3  2      0  0.0
# 4  2      0  0.0
```

Edit, considering updates in question.

```
dt <- data.frame(id = c(1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3),
             choice = c(0,0,"A","A","B",0,0,0), relevant = c(0,1,1,0,1,1,0,0))

chosen_value = "A"

# we use by to apply custom function to data frames split by id
within(dt, pct <- unlist(by(dt, dt$id, function(x) 
rep(
    if (sum(x$relevant == 1) == 0) 0 else {
    mean((x$choice == chosen_value)[x$relevant == 1])}
    , nrow(x))
)))

#   id choice relevant pct
# 1  1      0        0 0.5
# 2  1      0        1 0.5
# 3  1      A        1 0.5
# 4  2      A        0 0.0
# 5  2      B        1 0.0
# 6  2      0        1 0.0
# 7  3      0        0 0.0
# 8  3      0        0 0.0
```

Comment: This is well done, I wonder if you can extend it to cover the case where only a subset of values for `choice` should be propagated over `id` (see revision of question)

Answer (score 1):

In base R:

`df$pct <- 100*tapply(df$choice, df$id, mean)[df$id]`

For the subset having `relevant == 1`:

`df$pct <- 100*tapply(df$choice, df[, c('id', 'relevant')], mean)[df$id, "1"]`

Comment: this looks really close to what the updated version of the question specifies. Can you extend your solution?

Comment: thanks a lot! I must say that is pretty opaque syntax to the non-initiated. As a side note (and I know this is a reach), in my non-minimal actual project it seems that tapply() produces a vector with fewer rows than my full frame. Any likely suspects for that?

Answer (score 0):

For your example this code will do the job:

```
library(dplyr)
df <-data.frame(id = c(1,1,2,2),
           choice = c(0,1,0,0))

df %>% group_by(id) %>%
      mutate(percent=mean(choice)*100)

# A tibble: 4 x 3
# Groups:   id [2]
     id choice percent
  <dbl>  <dbl>   <dbl>
1  1.00   0       50.0
2  1.00   1.00    50.0
3  2.00   0        0  
4  2.00   0        0
```

Think in terms of using `mutate` coupled with `group_by` rather then `summarise`

Answer (score 0):

A dplyr solution:

```
df %>%
  filter(relevant==1) %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  summarize(pct1 = 100*sum(choice==1)/n()) %>%
  right_join(df)

# # A tibble: 6 x 4
#      id  pct1 choice relevant
#   <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl>    <dbl>
# 1     1    50      0        0
# 2     1    50      0        1
# 3     1    50      1        1
# 4     2     0      1        0
# 5     2     0      0        1
# 6     2     0      0        1
```